# Dynamically create input field and store those attributes in db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a case where I need to create a model where its attributes aren’t specific right now. The attributes (Product->name, Product->price) are created by the users and so the input fields should be created dynamically too and those values are needed to be store.
Any suggestions how to get it done?
Note: I am not an expert on laravel, any detailed approach will be helpful.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing an EAV model

Comment: I don't know what is an EAV model, but that keyword will help me in an extended way. Thanks btw.